# Sql query with optional fields for Search Web Application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-mvc

**Not an SQL expert:**

I am currently implementing a Searching Web Application. The user will send a `GET request` to a particular `Endpoint`.

The `Endpoint` will accept a set of `URL Params` and the request can come with optional fields. Such as 1, 2 or 3 fields.

My Database table for `USER` looks like this.

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | firstName    | lastName | email | zip | phone      |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now the web application will get a `GET Request` with either `Phone` or `Zip` or `Email`.

I have two solutions for doing this but both look bad:

```
Solution 1:
```

1. Have multiple `SQL Queries` and `Execute` them according to the URL Params, I receive.

   `Select * from User where phone=1111111111  and zip=12345 and email=test@email.com;`

   `Select * from User where phone=1111111111 and zip=12345;`

   `...
   ...`

And so on........I will end up having many queries and this will be a bad implementation. Also will be bad to maintain.

```
Solution 2:
```

Other solution that I am thinking of is to have a method, which will build an SQL query based on the URL Params I receive.

Example:

```
buildSQLQuery(phone,zip,email){

String sql = "Select * from User where "

if(phone!=null  && email!=null && zip!=null ){
sql = sql   + "phone = " + phone + " and zip = " + zip + " and email = " + email;
}else if (phone!=null  && email!=null && zip==null){
sql = sql + "phone = " + phone + " and email = " + email;
}
.......
......
And so on have all conditions and build that particular query.
}
```

**I don't like both these solutions.**

Is there a way to write a Single SQL query and that will handle all the above conditions.

Something like if the URL Param value is `NULL` then that should not affect the query and I will get my expected results.

As in my case the optional values, which don't come in are set to `NULL`.

Can I implement something like this?

```
Select * from User where (if notNull (phone))(phone = phone ) and (if notNull (email))(email = email ) and (if notNull (zip))(zip = zip )
```

If any of the above one value is null then don't use that part in  `where Condition`.

Also I will always have one field present, so there will be no case where all values are null.

I am implementing this web application in Java and Spring MVC. If anyone can guide me in the correct direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can do that with `if()` if you provide `fiddle` for your table here it will be easy to find solution.

Comment: You are using Spring MVC. I highly recommend you usage of Spring Data JPA and Hibernate framework. http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/ Then you will not have to write SQL boilerplate code like this.

Comment: Can you give me an example for using spring-data-jpa? in my case.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990281/how-to-form-a-sql-query-dynamically-based-on-the-input-field-values) too.

Answer (score 1):

I think one more possible solution like:

```
String sql = "Select * from User where 1=1 "

    if(phone!=null){
    sql +=  " and phone = " + phone ;}

    if(email!=null){
    sql +=  " and email = " + email ;}

    if(zip!=null){
    sql +=  " and zip = " + zip ;}
```

OR You can try following single query:

```
select * from User 
where (@phone is null OR phone = @phone) AND (@email is null OR email = @email) AND (@zip is null OR zip = @zip)
```

Comment: Be careful, SQL injection is strongly possible here.

Comment: I would be curious to see if this answer could be updated in such a way that SQL injection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM User where(
   IF($phone != 0, IF(phone = $phone,1,0), 0) AND 
   IF($email != 0, IF(email = $email,1,0),0) AND 
   IF($zip != 0, IF(zip = $zip,1,0),0)
)
```

assumed for PHP you can change the syntax, may be this query not do the job completely but if you provide fiddle i will modify this to give the proper result.